# Objective-C NSDictionary value comparison

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am returning a string of either T or F from an NSDictionary key value pair.  I'm trying to find out if it is the T or the F, but it never works like I would expect it to.  I'm sure there is a very basic solution for this issue.

```
if ([game objectForKey:@"complete"] == @"T") never evaluates to true.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change that to:

```
if ([[game objectForKey:@"complete"] isEqualToString: @"T"])
```

What you were doing was comparing pointers to strings, not their contents.

Comment: So, to compare two values in two NSDictionaries, I should do 

    `if ([[simData objectForKey:@"lineState"] isEqualToString: [[previousUpdate objectForKey:@"lineState"]]])...` ?